# Image resize with browser not working

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to resize my logo image when the user adjusts their browsers width.

```
    <div id="header">
    <div class="header_top_section">
                        <a href="http://carcarlease.com" class="desktop_logo site_logo"><img src="http://carcarlease.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo3.png" alt="" class="logo"></a></div>
```

As you can see I have given my image the class name of "logo".

In my stylesheet I have defined these properties that are supposed to achieve this.

```
.logo{
max-width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}
```

However, this has had no effect. You can see the result here: http://www.carcarlease.com

Comment: check the div of "header_top_section". that div sealed your image.

Comment: I have been stuck with this issue for over an hour and I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/2273/)

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

No need for `!important`

Comment: I am aware, however the same code is on my website and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The code of Jatin works fine in here, or maybe you are looking for this?

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/2274/)

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Note: I can't view the link you provided due to firewall security.